# Bluetooth Low Energy (between ESP32 and Android smartphone): Data transmission quite slow

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

***This is my first question ever asked on this board***

> 

**The project explained short:**

> 5 sensors, connected with an esp32 board are transmitting 1000 samples/second, each sample has 16 bit. Those values should be transmitted via BLE (With the BLE Arduino library and an ESP32). The connected device (Smartphone) should read those values and do something with them (Also via BLE, with the following library: https://github.com/RobotPajamas/Blueteeth). **The ESP32 is the Server!** **Java is used in Android Studio!**

**The problem:**

> While testing the BLE connection a simple "hello world" was transmitted as the value for a characteristic. Every time i received the "hello world" on the android-device-side, a variable was incremented: The problem is, **the variable only got incremented 4 times in one second.** This means (assuming 1 char in a string equals 1 byte) 11byte*4(1/s)=44byte/s are being transmitted. -> This clearly is not enough (should not BLE transmit ~2MBit/s (minus the protocol-data))

**Code Fragments**

> ESP32: BLE-Server that transmits value

```
#include <BLEDevice.h>
#include <BLEUtils.h>
#include <BLEServer.h>


#define SERVICE_UUID        "4fafc201-1fb5-459e-8fcc-c5c9c331914b"
#define CHARACTERISTIC_UUID "beb5483e-36e1-4688-b7f5-ea07361b26a8"


class MyCallbacks: public BLECharacteristicCallbacks {
    void onWrite(BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic) {
      std::string value = pCharacteristic->getValue();

      if (value.length() > 0) {
        Serial.println("*********");
        Serial.print("New value: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); i++)
          Serial.print(value[i]);

        Serial.println();
        Serial.println("*********");
      }
    }
};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  BLEDevice::init("MyESP32");
  BLEServer *pServer = BLEDevice::createServer();

  BLEService *pService = pServer->createService(SERVICE_UUID);

  BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
                                         CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ |
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE
                                       );

  pCharacteristic->setCallbacks(new MyCallbacks());

  pCharacteristic->setValue("Hello World");
  pService->start();

  BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = pServer->getAdvertising();
  pAdvertising->start();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  delay(2000);
}
```

> Android Studio Code (Snippet of the receiving source):

```
try
        {
            while(sampleBluetoothData)
            {
                this.selectedDevice.readCharacteristic(MainActivity.characteristicUUID, MainActivity.serviceUUID, (response, data) ->
                {
                    if (response != BlueteethResponse.NO_ERROR) {
                            return;
                    }
                    Log.d("AUSGANG", new String(data) + "times: "+ i);
                    i++;
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The write on the ESP32 side is a blank example code of the Arduino IDE, the read on the Android-side is made by the BLE-Library publisher. Yes the Log.d effects the performance, but it does not drop it that much.

> The variable "data" of the Android code is the received char-array. The bluetooth-reading runs on a background thread.

**Question I ask myself now:**

- Is the Android-Studio library the problem or the Arduino library
- Is this a normal behaviour, that if a value of a characteristic does not change, it is being transmitted quite slowly.
- How fast can you update a value of a characteristic

> 

**Thank you in advance!**

Comment: You should use Characteristic Notifications instead of Characteristic Reads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BLE can definitely transfer much more than 4 portions of 11 bytes per second.

Approach of reading:

1. Generally, continuos reading all the time is NOT the expected BLE way - it's better to subscribe to data changes, so ESP32 will notify only when needed (e.g. do `selectedDevice.subscribeToCharacteristic` once, instead of reading in a loop, but then ESP32 code should be changed accordingly)
2. I guess `selectedDevice.readCharacteristic` requests asynchronous BLE read, and when you call it in `while(sampleBluetoothData)`, your Bluetooth library is adding more and more read requests. Maybe it would be wise to request new read only after the previous read is done - in read callback add `if(sampleBluetoothData) { this.readAgain(); }`

Consider making a testing prototype from this kickstart example: [BLEProof on github](https://github.com/alexanderlavrushko/BLEProof-collection) - **Android & ESP32, read, write, notify** (but it uses just system API without Bluetooth library, you approach is better, it's easier and safer to use the library).

What else to check:

1. Android side: are you sure that your code doesn't go inside of `if (response != BlueteethResponse.NO_ERROR)` ?
2. Android side: to ensure Bluetooth library is not overloaded with read requests, try adding a delay 50 milliseconds in the reading loop (just to check, it's not a solution)
3. Android side: are you sure that you don't have other BLE read/writes while you read those data?
4. ESP32 side: use shorter BLE connection interval ([BLE throughput article](https://punchthrough.com/ble-throughput-part-4/)) - add `pAdvertising->setMinPreferred(0x06);` and `pAdvertising->setMaxPreferred(0x20);` before `pAdvertising->start();` (but that sets only "preferred" interval, Android may ignore that)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer!
It seems like i use an old library version, on this version (2.0) subscriptions were not possible. I updated to version 4.0, now it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Using read requests, you are mainly limited by the connection interval for transfer speeds - that is 2 intervals for request + response.

If for example your client has a connection interval of 50ms, you should expect to read a characteristic of up to 20 bytes 10 times per second.

If another client has a connection interval of 30ms, this rate improves to 16.6 reads per second.

The fastest negotiatiable connection interval is 7.5ms for a maximum of 66.6 reads per second (10.7kbps with 20 byte reads).

Answer (score 0):

I was reading BLE wikipedia page and the minimum data rate is 125Kbit/s , so I think that in your case is viable, because you only will transmit 16Kbit/s. Take a look in [BLE wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_Low_Energy).